Help identify shower valve type
[picture of valve]2I’m hoping someone can help me identify which type of valve this is for my shower. I’m looking to update the trim only and just find something that works with the current valve. It is American Standard.

just get a new valve and trim that match for sure. Not even knowing the make gives you a high chance of not matching something - either the shape or depth etc

Thank you! I know it’s American Standard but it’s hard to tell what could replace it. Switching out valves is a good bit of work right? It may be a pressure valve, but still trying to identify it. Wasn’t sure if just replacing existing American Standard trim with other AS would be the easiest option.

It's an older American Standard valve.  The issue is finding trim that line up with the screw holes.  As you are probably finding this is difficult, since the modern trims won't fit.
Two options ;
Take the old trim to a plumbing supply company to match or order something new.
Look online for trim adapter plates. The plates are mounted to the valves and then the trim can be put on.  These change the screw positions so new trim can be used on old valves.
